# Binding Resolution Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

What is the difference between

```
$this->app->when('App\Http\Controllers\StaffController')
      ->needs('App\Repositories\User\UserInterface')
      ->give('App\Repositories\User\StaffRepository');
```

This one works!

```
$this->app->when(StaffController::class)
      ->needs(UserInterface::class)
      ->give(StaffRepository::class);
```

But this one doesn't work. What's the problem?

Comment: I'd imagine it's a namespacing issue. Does `App\Http\Controllers\StaffController::class` instead of `StaffController::class` etc. work? What errors are you getting?

Comment: No, still it doesn't work.

Comment: **What errors are you getting?**

Comment: `Target [App\Repositories\User\UserInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\StaffController].`

Comment: Does `$this->app->when(\App\Http\Controllers\StaffController::class)->needs(\App\Repositories\User\UserInterface::class)->give(\App\Repositories\User\StaffRepository::class);` work?

Comment: Yeah It works. Thanks, it's a namespace problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this works:

```
$this->app->when(\App\Http\Controllers\StaffController::clas‌​s)
  ->needs(\App\Repos‌​itories\User\UserInt‌​erface::class)
  ->give‌​(\App\Repositories\U‌​ser\StaffRepository:‌​:class);
```

you have a namespace issue. You can use this as-is with the leading `\`s, but chances are putting this at the top of the file will resolve it:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\StaffController;
use App\Repos‌​itories\User\UserInt‌​erface;
use App\Repositories\U‌​ser\StaffRepository;
```